# osquery daemond won't start on Ubuntu 15

Tags: ubuntu

Cannot start osquery on Ubuntu 15:

I am getting this in the logs:

```
● osqueryd.service - LSB: run osqueryd daemon    Loaded: loaded
(/etc/init.d/osqueryd)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue
2015-08-18 05:15:09 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 27710 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/osqueryd start (code=exited, status=127)

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: run osqueryd daemon...

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 osqueryd[27710]: osqueryd: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 systemd[1]: osqueryd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: run osqueryd daemon.

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Unit osqueryd.service entered failed state.

Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 systemd[1]: osqueryd.service failed.
```

This is how I installed it:

```
dpkg -i osquery-latest.deb

apt-get install osquery
```

So why is it not starting?

Comment: That's a pretty sucky package, if it doesn't declare dependencies on the library packages it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key error is right here

```
Aug 18 05:15:09 public-server-01 osqueryd[27710]: osqueryd: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Looks like you are missing `libgcrypt.so.11` Looks like that's a 14.04 and not available in 15. From reading it seems you can install the 14.04 version though.

Comment: I tried installing libgcrypt11 with apt-get but it did not change anything.

Comment: I got it from: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb